# Bindings not working using custom control

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make a custom control with Binding and my Binding of an ImageSource isn't working. That's my code:

Customcontrol.xaml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="Custom.CustomEntry"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

            <ImageButton
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                Clicked="Open"
                Source="{Binding Icon}" />



            <Frame
                x:Name="frameemojis"
                BackgroundColor="red"
                IsVisible="False">
                <Label Text="Hello" />
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

CustomControl.xaml.cs:

public partial class CustomControl: ContentView
{
public static readonly BindableProperty IconProperty =
BindableProperty.Create("Icon", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(CustomControl));

```
    public ImageSource Icon
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }



    bool state = true;
    void Open(object o, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        if (state)
        {
            state = false;
            frameemojis.IsVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            state = true;
            frameemojis.IsVisible = false;
        }

    }



    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

}

MainPage.xaml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="App23.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:fav="clr-namespace:Custom;assembly=Custom">

    <StackLayout>
        <fav:CustomControl Icon="icon.png" WidthRequest="200" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = new ViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The ViewModel now is empty but in the future I will use it to control other things. My idea is to set the icon in the MainPage with **Icon="icon.png"**. Any idea why isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the code of Custom View like following .

#### in xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="Custom.CustomEntry"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     x:Name="CustomView"   //set name of custom view
    >
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

            <ImageButton
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                Clicked="Open"
                Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView},Path=Icon}" />



            <Frame
                x:Name="frameemojis"
                BackgroundColor="red"
                IsVisible="False">
                <Label Text="Hello" />
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but I have a question. Why to other people the binding works with only Source="{Binding Icon}"  and I need to write all this  Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference CustomView},Path=Icon}" ?

Comment: We need to set the binding path directly in custom view . In contentpage it will work .

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties)

> The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable property identifier must match the property name specified in the Create method, with "Property" appended to it.

So you should rename `LeftSideIconProperty` to `IconProperty` or `Icon` to `LeftSideIcon`.

Comment: Still not working, I edited the post with my code now. I rename LeftSideIconProperty  to IconProperty and still getting a blank screen.

Comment: I restarted VS and now yes, I get this error. System.MissingFieldException: 'Field not found: Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty Custom.CustomEntry.IconProperty Due to: Could not find

Comment: It looks like you have a mismatch between `CustomEntry` and `CustomControl`

Comment: I tried to do the same in other project with same names and same error. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You have a declaration `x:Class="Custom.CustomEntry` in `Customcontrol.xaml`, but your class itself is named `CustomControl`. Is it a typo for this example?

Comment: The names are example names. Don't worry, Lucas Zhang solved my problem.