# Binding on Property not working in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a custom `ContentView` that can be used throughout my `Xamarin.Froms` application in de xaml views. The binding on `IconColor` is not working. I followed the documentation [ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview#define-ui) but it does not seem to work. The Color of the `FontImageSource` is never set. What am I missing here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="Peripass.Mobile.Framework.UIControls.PeripassIcon"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
  <ContentView.Resources>
  </ContentView.Resources>
  <ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Image>
        <Image.Source>
          <FontImageSource x:Name="_icon" Glyph="" Color="{Binding IconColor}" Size="20" FontFamily="{OnPlatform  Android=PeripassIcon.ttf#}" />
        </Image.Source>
      </Image>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

```
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Peripass.Mobile.Framework.UIControls {
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class PeripassIcon : ContentView {

    public static readonly BindableProperty IconSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconSize), typeof(double), typeof(PeripassIcon), 26.0);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconColor), typeof(Color), typeof(PeripassIcon), Color.White);
    public static readonly BindableProperty IconNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IconName), typeof(IconType?), typeof(PeripassIcon));

    public PeripassIcon() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IconType IconName {
      get => (IconType)GetValue(IconNameProperty);
      set => SetValue(IconNameProperty, value);
    }

    public double IconSize {
      get => (double)GetValue(IconSizeProperty);
      set => SetValue(IconSizeProperty, value);
    }

    public Color IconColor {
      get => (Color)GetValue(IconColorProperty);
      set => SetValue(IconColorProperty, value);
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null) {
      base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
      if (propertyName == IconNameProperty.PropertyName) {
        _icon.Glyph = $"&#x{(int)IconName:X4};";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
    <uiControls:PeripassIcon IconName="{Binding Model.Icon}" IconColor="#EE4022" IconSize="85.5"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: You might need to set the `BindingContext` of the control to itself. I am not super familiar with Xamarin.Forms, just taking a guess here.

Comment: That did the trick

Comment: You could check my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64695781/bindings-not-working-using-custom-control/64696448#64696448.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to set the BindingContext like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentView
    x:Class="Peripass.Mobile.Framework.UIControls.PeripassIcon"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="this">
  <ContentView.Resources>
  </ContentView.Resources>
  <ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference this}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Image>
        <Image.Source>
          <FontImageSource x:Name="_icon" Glyph="" Color="{Binding IconColor}" Size="{Binding IconSize}" FontFamily="{OnPlatform  Android=PeripassIcon.ttf#}" />
        </Image.Source>
      </Image>
    </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Answer (score -1):

A best practice in MVVM is to keep Views separate from ViewModels, so the best approach is to set BindingContext to the ViewModel (not View via `{x:Reference this}`).

Make sure that either in Code behind or in Xaml the page binding context is set to your ViewModel, the rest is defined correctly.